# NSData has size but image is not reaching server returning empty

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsdata, image-uploading

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 for uploading single image am storing image which selected from UIImgePhotoLibrary and i convereted it to NSData i can see that NSData holds some data when i try to upload its returning that there is no image reached server and its not even taking time just returning error in a sec of time. Am frasturating with this problem for past few days i don know where am exactly got logged ?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{


     UIImage *image =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"CONTENT_LENGTH"];

    [manager POST:@"http://xxxxx.com/appphotos/fileupload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image/jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", operation.responseString);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error debugDescription]);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"response :%@",operation.responseString);
    }];



    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

could any one help or pls let me know if i did blunder mistake any where. thx in advance

Comment: Look at what is actually sent ad the server response with a network analyzer like Charles Proxy.

Comment: @Zaph i ve analysed in that it shows image content

Comment: You have used a network analyzer, your reply does not state how/what you have analyzed. So the server does not like some aspect of the POST, you need to read the server upload docs carefully and review that what is sent exactly meets those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I created an app which uploads photos to a server. I only got it to work once I included the below code BUT this could be different from server to server so you might have to do what Zaph suggested and read up on your server docs. That being said, try out the code and maybe you get lucky :)

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/yourServerMethodHere/"];
    //[myString appendString:@"anyAdditionalURLpartHere"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myString]
                                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                            timeoutInterval:60];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundaryQkZe6RUJZ2xbzXLB";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"YOURserverVariableStoringTheIncomingData\" filename=\"image001.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:photoData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```